# No IP address on hotplug ethernet on embedded Linux

Tags: embedded-linux, ethernet, hotplugging

I have a problem with hotplug ethernet in an embedded Linux (ver 3.6.0-rc5).
If the network cable is connected during boot everything works fine.
But if I connect the cable after boot I do not get an IP address.

My /etc/interfaces look like this:

```
# The loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Wired or wireless interfaces
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

My startup script includes this command:

```
ifup eth0
```

If the ethernet cable is connected at boot I get this after calling 'ifup eth0':

```
[   10.257995] davinci_mdio davinci_mdio.0: resetting idled controller
[   10.265319] net eth0: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=davinci_mdio-0:00, id=7c0f1)
udhcpc (v1.19.4) started
Sending discover...
[   12.261260] libphy: davinci_mdio-0:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
Sending discover...
Sending select for 192.168.86.100...
Lease of 192.168.86.100 obtained, lease time 86400
adding dns 192.168.86.1
```

If the ethernet cable is not connected at boot I get this after calling 'ifup eth0':

```
[   10.230285] davinci_mdio davinci_mdio.0: resetting idled controller
[   10.238037] net eth0: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=davinci_mdio-0:00, id=7c0f1)
udhcpc (v1.19.4) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
No lease, failing
```

If I then connect the ethernet cable I get this:

```
[  346.232391] libphy: davinci_mdio-0:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
```

But I do not get an IP address.

So, it appears that Linux knows that the cable got connected, but it doesn't automatically ask for an IP address.
Note: If I do not call ifup during boot then nothing happens when I connect the ethetnet cable.

When the cable is connected I can get an IP address by doing this:

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Do I have to tell Linux to look for an address (e.g. ifdown/ifup)?
And if so: how do I do that?

Comment: After pluggin the cable in what happen if you do ifup eth0 again?

Comment: Not sure this apply: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192671/what-is-a-hotplug-event-from-the-interface

Comment: @pippo1980 If I do ifdown and then ifup I do get an IP address. So if there is a script which gets called when the cable is connected then I guess I could just put ifdown/ifup in that script.

Comment: used to play with openwrt a while ago ... but forgot everything ... think is related on how hotplug events are  handled by your sytem but can't help sorry

Comment: Look for udev but not sure all embedded systems have it (maybe something similar but smaller) : /etc/udev/rules.d/